# automatic script to copy folders on periodic intervals

Tags: centos7

iam using centos 7

i have the following script to copy specific folder and let it called Source

to destination folder called Destination every half an hour

and i want source folder to be named Source+currentdate under destination folder

where i should put this script to be executed every half an hour

```
 Today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H%M")
cd /
BACKUP_PATH='Destination'
cd ${BACKUP_PATH}
mkdir ${Source}.{Today}
```

and what is wrong in my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will offer a script i made a long time ago. You are free to use it.
This bash script will take a folder and tar.gz it and put it in a backup folder.

```
#!/bin/bash
TIME=`date +%b-%d-%y`                    # This Command will add date in 
# Backup File Name.
FILENAME=backup-$TIME.tar.gz  # Here i define Backup file name 
format.
SRCDIR=/opt/files/                         # Location of Important Data 
# Directory (Source of backup).
DESDIR=/opt/backups                  # Destination of backup file.
tar -cpzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR
```

Then save it to something like

```
 /usr/bin/backup.sh
```

And make sure to allow the system to run the command by using chmod

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/backup.sh
```

To make the script run every half an hour. You need to configure crontap. One way to do that is running this command.

```
crontab -e
```

and add the following line

```
30 * * * *  /usr/bin/backup.sh
```

I Hope you found this helpful :)

Comment: i have issued 1 * * * * root /copyscript1.sh

Comment: i have issued crontab -e and then add the following line 1 * * * * root /copyscript1.sh   becuase i want my script to be launched every minute and iam logging as root then i issued /sbin/service crond restart

Comment: with the following output of /sbin/service crond status
Aug 10 09:31:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Command Scheduler.
Aug 10 09:31:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Command Scheduler...
Aug 10 09:31:56 localhost.localdomain crond[2837]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 62% if used.)
Aug 10 09:31:56 localhost.localdomain crond[2837]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
Aug 10 09:31:56 localhost.localdomain crond[2837]: (CRON) INFO (@reboot jobs will be run at computer's startup.)

Comment: i also edit vi /etc/crontab
to have the line 1 * * * * root /copyscript1.sh but with the same previous log

Comment: why iam not able to start my  cron job

Comment: Entvex,Angel Porlan

Comment: i found the solution to my problem ,i had to launch script every minute and what was wrong that i put 1 * * * * instead i have to put * * * * * which means every minute

Comment: I am happy you found the solution to your issue! :).

Answer (score 0):

you can just add to crontab that line if you don't want any complexity:

```
/usr/bin/tar czvf /destination/dir/backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d.%H_%M).tar /dir/to/backup
```

Also you can make a simple log file with week rotation

```
#!/bin/bash
# Date command expands to the day of week in cron format
LOG=/var/log/backup.$(date +%w).log
# Let's check if the log file is old, and if it is, we will empty before starting logging again  
# If day of the last backup not equal to today you put nothing to log (so you empty it)
if [[ $(tail -n1 $LOG | awk '{print $3}' ) != $(date +%d) ]]; then
     : > $LOG
fi
# Then you backup. This date command will format name as backup-YEAR-MONTH-DAY.HOUR_MINUTE.tar.gz
tar czvf /destination/dir/backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d.%H_%M).tar.gz /dir/to/backup
# This conditional redirects the echo to log file
if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
    echo "$(date) OK: Backup completed succesfully" >> $LOG
else
    echo "$(date) ERROR: Backup failed" >> $LOG
fi
```

The resultant log files will be like
backup.0.log backup.1.log etc....